# How to get grunt-watch to livereload the correct css file?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

My goal is to use grunt-watch to live reload my stylesheet whenever I save a change to the stylesheet.

My grunt file is below.

When I run grunt, the file is being watched as expected, but the correct css file is not reloaded.

I can see in the Chrome dev tools | "network" tab that some style sheets are being live-reloaded.

But, some style sheets are not being live-reloaded, including the one that I am making changes to.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there an error in my "files" option value?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
     watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.css',
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

};
```

Comment: you mentioned `style.css` but in your files list you have `styles.css`, typo?

Comment: Thanks for catching that. But, that was not the issue. "style.css" is a contrived example file name. I updated the question to use the singular "style.css".

Comment: Could you post your actual Gruntfile? Sometimes its the littlest thing that throws things off.

Comment: Kyle, you are probably right, but I can't post the actual Gruntfile. The path to my stylesheet contains some info that I don't want to make public. The only difference between my example and the real Gruntfile.js is the 'css/style.css'.

Comment: Kyle, I pasted in my actual grunt file. I changed the files value in my example to: **/*.css

Comment: Hmm sorry. The above works for me. Feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues but I suspect something else is going on in the gruntfile that I cant see.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I opened an issue: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The issue was a typo in the style sheet's 'link' tag.

The "rel" attribute had the S's uppercase, but they should be lower case.

Incorrect:

- <link rel="**StyleSheet**" ...

Correct:

- <link rel="**stylesheet**" ...

The style sheet works fine on the live site (site displays properly), but was not being live-reloaded by the script used by grunt-contrib-watch.

Once I corrected the typo, the style sheets started to live-reload as expected.

Answer (score 0):

While this might not be an actual "solution" of the Grunt config issue itself (whether it's grunt internal issue or config issue). I could still suggest using a [CSS Reload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-reloader/dnfpcpfijpdhabaoieccoclghgplmpbd?hl=en) plugin for this task.

You can then either use keyboard shortcut (<kbd>F9</kbd> by default) or an option in context menu to reload all CSS files without reloading whole page:

[image]

This is, of course, not as elegant as having Grunt to do all the dirty work, but is a bulletproof solution.

Comment: Thanks mishik. I've been using the Google Chrome tincr extension to do live CSS reloading. http://tin.cr/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [Chrome LiveReload extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei?hl=en)?

Also make sure you are using the right ports and nothing is conflicting. LiveReload runs by default on port `35729`, you can pass a different port if you wish via the Gruntfile `watch` task.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Chrome Live Reload Extension. How can I check to see if there is a conflict?

Comment: Grunt watch will issue an alert if there is something else on the LiveReload port (like the LiveReload app).

Comment: Thanks. I get no alerts from Grunt.

Comment: Hmm, weird. Try modifying your file path in your options block to something like `/*.css` and see what that does.